# Не приходят данные по Bluetooth (RfcommDeviceService)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bluetooth

Есть устройство Bluetooth, которое в режиме комп порта передаёт-принимает данные.
После успешного подключения к устройству из кода вида

```
var btService = await RfcommDeviceService.FromIdAsync(deviceInformation.Id);
streamSocket = new StreamSocket();
await streamSocket.ConnectAsync(btService.ConnectionHostName, btService.ConnectionServiceName);
```

я произвожу отправку команды в поток:

```
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(command);
var writed = await streamSocket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(bytes.AsBuffer());
await streamSocket.OutputStream.FlushAsync();
```

Никаких ошибок нет, в переменной writed находится число байт, записанных в поток. Далее произвожу попытку чтения ответа:

```
IBuffer buffer = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer(256);
var message = await streamSocket.InputStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 256, InputStreamOptions.None);
```

На методе `ReadAsync()` приложение зависает (код не выполняется дальше). Нет никаких исключений, просто код стоит на этой строчке.

Пробовал отправлять/писать и другим способом, через `DataReader`/`DataWriter`, в целом происходит тоже самое.

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: `Read`/`ReadAsync` не возвращают данные, если в стриме их нет, и ждут до тех пор, пока данные там не появятся. Вы уверены, что устройство вам (уже) шлет ответ? Есть какой-то еще способ узнать это (дебаг/логирование в самом устройстве)?

Comment: @andreycha в аналогичной программе для android с этого устройства приходит ответ